# Why "foo".toString() is not the same as toString.call("foo")?

Tags: javascript

Here is a question in JavaScript below:

```
// Tested via Google Chrome console.
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

"foo".toString(); // "foo"
toString.call("foo"); // [object String]

[].toString(); // ""
toString.call([]); // [object Array]

{}.toString(); // syntax error
toString.call({}); // [object Object]
```

Why the result of toString is different with toString.call() ?

**UPDATED**

```
String.prototype.toString.call("foo"); // "foo"
Object.prototype.toString.call("foo"); // [object String]
```

Is String.prototype.toString not from the prototype chain like below?

> toString in String[not found]  --> toString in String.prototype[not found]
>
> ```
>                            --> toString in Object.prototype[found]
> ```

Comment: Not a javascript expert, but I would suspect it has to do with calling a predefined function and passing it a null parameter as opposed to calling a function on a nonexistent object.

Comment: How do you inspect those results? Browser console, or something else?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Chrome Browser console.

Comment: I thought it was just bad display of the browser, but looks like I was wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`String.prototype.toString` overrides `Object.prototype.toString`. They are not the same function.

From the [specification of `String.prototype.toString`](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.5.4.2):

> Returns this String value. (Note that, for a String object, the **toString** method happens to return the same thing as the **valueOf** method.)

And [`Object.prototype.toString`](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.2.4.2):

> When the **toString** method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *O* be the result of calling ToObject passing the **this** value as the argument.
> 2. Let *class* be the value of the [[Class]] internal property of *O*.
> 3. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings "**[object** ", *class*, and "**]**".

Arrays behave similar, they also override `toString()`:

```
> [1,2].toString()
  "1,2"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> String.prototype.toString.call("foo")
"foo"
```

Object is not the same thing as a String.

Comment: Is it right that the **toString** method of String is from `String.__proto__` ? And `String.__proto__` should be `Object`, so why **toString** in String is not equal to **toString** in Object?

Comment: Yes, but String overrides Objects toString to show a friendlier printout than just [Object X]. If it didn't override the default toString your thinking would be right.

Answer (score -1):

The global `toString` function is different to the `object.toString()` function.
According to [this source](http://thingsilearned.posterous.com/javascript-mystery-of-tostring-global-functio), the global `toString` function is not very well defined, and thus badly implemented across different browsers. Essentially it provides functionality similar to the `typeof` operator.

Comment: the toString OP is referring is not the not-well-defined "global toString", but very well-defined as "var toString = Object.prototype.toString" by the OP

Comment: My eyes must have passed over that first line of code. Apologies.