# Converting a function to its string representation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I know that calling `toString` on function object would give me the string representation of the function definition like:

`function foo() { /*...*/ }.toString();` works fine for me.

But [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/auto/injector.js#L78)

```
function stringifyFn(fn) {
  // Support: Chrome 50-51 only
  // Creating a new string by adding `' '` at the end, to hack around some bug in Chrome v50/51
  // (See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14487.)
  // TODO (gkalpak): Remove workaround when Chrome v52 is released
  return Function.prototype.toString.call(fn) + ' ';
}
```

I see that author has used this pattern in many places, what could be the reasons behind it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692961/why-foo-tostring-is-not-the-same-as-tostring-callfoo

Comment: To circumvent `funcName.toString = function() {return "not what you expect";}`

Comment: @AlexK. you mean someone may monkey path the function definition?

Comment: Yes, there is no restriction on overriding toString

Comment: b.t.w, this is not called *monkey patching*. In fact, this approach depends on **NOT** monkey patching. This approach prevents you from *accidently* creating/overriding `toString` property to your `fn` object. e.g. `fn.toString = 1` then call`fn.toString()` will throw error of `Uncaught TypeError: fooFn.toString is not a function(…)` ...